# Can I stop iPhone apps from changing my Gmail status?

Tags: iphone, gmail, google-voice

I recently got the Mo+ GV iPhone app to replace talkatone and it's a thousand times better. The problem is is that when I'm logged in (It connects to GTalk/voice) my gmail status is changed to an annoying ad. something like "I'm using Mo+ get it now at blah blah", and I know a lot of other apps do this too. Is there a way to disable this from happening? (Its not in the app settings)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you mean this app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phone-for-google-voice-talk/id541829441?mt=8 Since the app is free, it's reasonable to have ads. You could email the developer and ask for it to be removed in the next release.

Or, if you don't mind losing the Google Voice integration, you could go with [Verbs ($1)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/verbs-im/id392501688?mt=8), which is an IM app.

Less reliable way to fix it: After signing in with Mo+ GV, sign into Gtalk from somewhere else (like your computer). I think only the most recent status will be displayed.

Insane way to fix it: Jailbreak your iPhone to disable code signing. Then, find the "I'm using Mo+…" string in the application's binary and change it to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by clicking on the status symbol to the top right corner, then click on your email, then click "signature." You can type something else to show, but if you delete it entirely it reverts to that terrible default message to your contacts. I hate Mo+.